# Using Array.prototype.filter to filter nested children objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects similar to the following block of code:

```js
var arr = [
 {
     text: 'one',
        children: [
         {
             text: 'a',
                children: [
                 {
                        text: 'something'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
             text: 'b'
            },
            {
             text: 'c'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
     text: 'two'
    },
    {
     text: 'three'
    },
    {
     text: 'four'
    }
];
```

In the above structure, I want to search a string in `text` property and I need to perform this search over all the `children`.

For example, if I search for `something`, the result should be an array of object in the following form:

```js
[
 {
        children: [
         {
                children: [
                 {
                        text: 'something'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Notice all the `text` properties that do not match the input string `something` have been deleted.

I have come up with the following block of code using `Array.prototype.filter`. However, I can still see extra properties in the result:

```js
function search(arr, str) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
     if(obj.children && obj.children.length > 0) {
          return search(obj.children, str);
        }
        
 if(obj.text === str) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          delete text;
          return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbx2dafg/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if there would be more `text` properties with `something` value ? Like `children: [
         {
             text: 'a',
                children: [
                 {
                        text: 'something'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
             text: 'b'
            },
            {
             text: 'something'
            }
        ]`. How should look the result in such case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because filter returns an array, which is needed, but not practical for this purpose, because it returns all children with it.

This proposal generates a new array out of the found items, with the wantes item `text` and `children`.

The solution works iterative and recursive. It finds all occurences of the search string.

```js
function filter(array, search) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var temp = [],
            o = {},
            found = false;

        if (a.text === search) {
            o.text = a.text;
            found = true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            temp = filter(a.children, search);
            if (temp.length) {
                o.children = temp;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            result.push(o);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var array = [{ text: 'one', children: [{ text: 'a', children: [{ text: 'something' }] }, { text: 'b' }, { text: 'c' }] }, { text: 'two' }, { text: 'three' }, { text: 'four' }];

console.log(filter(array, 'something'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `search` returns an array with object from "parent" level, that's why you *"still see extra properties in the result"*.
Secondly, this line `delete text;` doesn't delete an object or object property - it should be `delete obj.text;`.
 Here is solution using additional `Array.map` fuinction:

```
function search(arr, str) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        if (obj.text !== str) {
           delete obj.text;
        }
        if (obj.children && obj.children.length > 0) {
           return search(obj.children, str);
        }

        if (obj.text === str) {
           return true;
        } else {
           delete obj.text;
           return false;
        }
    });
}

var result = search(arr, 'something').map(function(v) {  // filtering empty objects
   v['children'] = v['children'].filter((obj) => Object.keys(obj).length);
   return {'children':v['children'] };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result,0,4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "something"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75nrmL1o/